# Automatic installation of plugins in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, automatic-install

For my project in Android Studio I need a plugin. Since I want other developers to use and test my code, they have to download the plugin manually when opening the project.
What could I implement that Android Studio automatically installs this plugin when a user opens the project (who has not already installed this plugin)?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Attach your [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) file with the project. The Gradle must contain all your required libraries and plugins mentioned.

Read, [Adding Custom Plugins](https://medium.com/groupon-eng/developing-android-studio-plugins-with-gradle-7597d8825d76) with Gradle.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The plugin should be downloaded from gitlab. So the Android Studio of other developers should install automatically this plugin. That is why I don't think it is possible with dependencies in gradle.build...